# Como linkar um arquivo .php numa página HTML?

Tags: php, html

As páginas do meu site são construidas assim:
index.php (este é um arquivo que possue apenas "requires", que requisitam páginas .php que possuem HTML, estas páginas irão montar a página em questão)
um dos requires do index (um arquivo que é HTML, a extensão dele é php) possue um link que deverá chamar um arquivo .php análogo ao index.php (um arquivo que possue "requires" e que, portanto, rodará no servidor)

O problema que estou tendo é de endereçamento: não sei como colocar o endereço (quero que seja endereçado a partir da raiz) no

Veja a imagem em anexo, penso que o problema ficará mais claro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é possível colocar como `href="<?= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/fisica/curso...">` ?

Answer (score -1):

Não precisa colocar o que vem antes no caminho, use o `./` caminho atual, ou seja:

A página atual é `www.seusite.com/pagina` e você usa o `<a href="./exemplo.php"></a>`, ao clicar vai para `www.seusite.com/pagina/exemplo.php`

Se usr com dois pontos, o caminho vai retroceder uma pasta:

A página atual é `www.seusite.com/pagina` e você usa o `<a href="../exemplo.php"></a>`, ao clicar vai para `www.seusite.com/exemplo.php`

Você pode usar você pode usar em cadeia para voltar mais de uma pasta ex:  `../../../exemplo`